# Как превратить обычное дропдаун меню в мультиселект дропдаун меню?

Tags: html, css

Есть такое меню:

```
<select>
 <option value="0" >Select</option>
 <option value="1" >1</option>
 <option value="2" >2</option>
 <option value="3" >3</option>
</select>
```

Как сделать из него chechbox меню на чистом html/js/css? Например, чтобы я мог выбрать 1,3 или 1,2.
Нужно что-то вроде этого. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<select multiple="multiple">` ?

Comment: @splash58 ломается меню когда я так делаю

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл вот такое решение:

```js
var expanded = false;

function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 200px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
      <select>
        <option>Select an option</option>
      </select>
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <label for="one">
        <input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox</label>
      <label for="two">
        <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox</label>
      <label for="three">
        <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне без jquery надо. Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Без jQuery можно, а можно ли обойтись без JavaScript пока не знаю. Хороший вопрос, интересный. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Выглядит неплохо, но в Вашем коде, если выстроить селекты в список , при нажатии на пятый Select an option, меню будет появляться всегда только под первым Select an option.